# Unclaimed Memory and Coprocessor

Tags: drivers

I have Ubuntu 12.10 and Asus K70IO. My memory and coprocessor are unclaimed.

```
    *-memory:0 UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: MCP79 Memory Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:00.1
       version: b1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz (15.2ns)
       capabilities: bus_master
       configuration: latency=0
  *-memory:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: MCP79 Memory Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 3.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.1
       version: b1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz (15.2ns)
       configuration: latency=0
  *-memory:2 UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: MCP79 Memory Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 3.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.3
       version: b1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz (15.2ns)
       configuration: latency=0
  *-processor UNCLAIMED
       description: Co-processor
       product: MCP79 Co-processor
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 3.5
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.5
       version: b1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: bus_master
       configuration: latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
       resources: memory:f7f80000-f7ffffff
```

MCP79 is my laptop's chipset so I conclude that chipset isn't installed correctly. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `UNCLAIMED` does not mean "not being used", it means the kernel has not addressed it. That is fine in systems that are designed to work without the operating system interfering with them.
- A RAM controller and RAM are not the same thing.

Unless you have an actual problem that you can point at these being the issue, I really wouldn't worry about these. Most people have unclaimed devices in fully working systems. I know I do.